# выдвигающееся боковое меню pyqt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

У меня есть код приложения, я хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии `pushButton_13` слева  на право открывалось или выдвигалось меню, с пунктами 1, 2, 3, и.т.д.
Можно ли это как-то осуществить?

код **nvutimain.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from nvutidesign import Ui_MainWindow


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**nvutidesign.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'e:/nvuti/nvutidesign.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.14.0
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(870, 569)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(870, 569))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(870, 569))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.011, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(182, 29, 212, 255), stop:1 rgba(48, 7, 182, 255));\n"
"")
        MainWindow.setAnimated(True)
        MainWindow.setDocumentMode(False)
        MainWindow.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 380, 221, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(141, 142, 161);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 380, 221, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(141, 142, 161);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 220, 201, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 781, 141))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(72)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(97, 118, 255);\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 260, 221, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"border: 2px solid gray;           \n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"pIntValidator.setRange(1, 95)")
        self.lineEdit.setMaxLength(99999)
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit.setReadOnly(False)
        self.lineEdit.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 460, 61, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 460, 61, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 490, 41, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_5.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 490, 41, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_6.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_6.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 460, 61, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_7.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_7.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 460, 61, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_8.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_8.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 490, 41, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_9.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_9.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_9.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")
        self.pushButton_10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 490, 41, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_10.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_10.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_10.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_10.setObjectName("pushButton_10")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 500, 841, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(50)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 480, 61, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(231, 231, 231);")
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.pushButton_11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 20, 101, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_11.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_11.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_11.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_11.setObjectName("pushButton_11")
        self.pushButton_12 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 20, 101, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_12.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_12.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_12.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 170, 170);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_12.setObjectName("pushButton_12")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 550, 61, 21))
        self.label_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 350, 28, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(507, 350, 161, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 260, 221, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.spinBox.setFont(font)
        self.spinBox.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"border: 2px solid gray;\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.spinBox.setWrapping(False)
        self.spinBox.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.spinBox.setButtonSymbols(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.NoButtons)
        self.spinBox.setPrefix("")
        self.spinBox.setMinimum(1)
        self.spinBox.setMaximum(95)
        self.spinBox.setSingleStep(1)
        self.spinBox.setProperty("value", 90)
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 310, 211, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 310, 47, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_9.setFont(font)
        self.label_9.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 21, 20))
        self.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 1px;")
        self.lineEdit_3.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.pushButton_13 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 51, 41))
        self.pushButton_13.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:clicked {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_13.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("e:/nvuti\\123.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton_13.setIcon(icon)
        self.pushButton_13.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(55, 55))
        self.pushButton_13.setFlat(False)
        self.pushButton_13.setObjectName("pushButton_13")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Nvuti"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Меньше"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Больше"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Возможный выигрыш"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0.00"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сумма"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Удвоить"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Половина"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Макс."))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Мин."))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Половина"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Удвоить"))
        self.pushButton_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Мин."))
        self.pushButton_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Макс."))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "700"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Баланс"))
        self.pushButton_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пополнить"))
        self.pushButton_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вывести"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Nvuti 2020©"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0-0"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "999999 - 999999"))
        self.spinBox.setSuffix(_translate("MainWindow", "%"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Максимальный процент - 95%"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "*"))
```

На примере скайпа

[image: На примере скайпа]

[image: На примере скайпа]

Comment: `он форматируется неправильно` а вы не просто код вставьте в вопрос, но и добавьте по \`\`\` выше и ниже кода

Comment: Смотрели в сторону QDockWidget? Их можно разместить на окне, таскать мышкой и т.п. Выглядит так: https://github.com/gil9red/directory-sizes/blob/master/README.md#directory-sizes

Comment: @gil9red Еще добавил скриншоты, один человек ответил, тоже попробую применить. Может вы сможете сделать это как на картинках которые я добавил в пример, тоесть прямо так как я описывал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не используете Layouts, поэтому говорить о чем-то выдвигающемся преждевременно.

А на счет меню - пожалуйста, только уберите из модуля `nvutidesign.py` все что связано с `pushButton_13` и обратите внимание на `lineEdit_3`, который был спрятан за `pushButton_13` и я его немного выдвинул, чтобы вы обратили внимание.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from nvutidesign import Ui_MainWindow

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.menu_bar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.menu_bar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1, 1, 51, 21))

        self.menu     = QtWidgets.QMenu('MENU', self)

        self.menu_action = QtWidgets.QAction('Option #1', self)
        # setData - Устанавливает внутренние данные действия в данные userData.
        self.menu_action.setData('option1')

        self.menu_action2 = QtWidgets.QAction('Option #2', self) 
        self.menu_action3 = QtWidgets.QAction('Option #3', self)

        self.menu_action.triggered.connect(self.actionClicked)
        self.menu_action2.triggered.connect(self.actionClicked)
        self.menu_action3.triggered.connect(self.actionClicked) 

        self.menu.addAction(self.menu_action)
        self.menu.addAction(self.menu_action2)                    
        self.menu.addAction(self.menu_action3)                    

        self.menu_bar.addMenu(self.menu)

    def actionClicked(self):
        action = self.sender()
        print(action.text())
        print(action.data())



if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> можно ли изменить размер Option #1,2 и 3? в ширину и длину?

Да, все возможно.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from nvutidesign import Ui_MainWindow

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.menu_bar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.menu_bar.setNativeMenuBar(False)                      # ???
        self.menu_bar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1, 1, 51, 21))

        self.menu     = QtWidgets.QMenu('MENU', self)

        self.menu_action = QtWidgets.QAction('Option #1', self)
        # setData - Устанавливает внутренние данные действия в данные userData.
        self.menu_action.setData('option1')

        self.menu_action2 = QtWidgets.QAction('Option #2', self) 
        self.menu_action3 = QtWidgets.QAction('Option #3', self)

        self.action4     = QtWidgets.QWidgetAction(self)             
        self.label4 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Hello \nWorld')                          
        self.action4.setDefaultWidget(self.label4);
        self.action4.setText('Hello World')
        self.label4.setStyleSheet("""
            QLabel { 
                background-color : red; 
                padding: 10px 12px 10px 12px; 
                min-width: 200px;
                color: #000;
                font: italic bold 16px;
            }
            QLabel:hover { background-color: #C10000; color: #fff;}
            """)



        self.menu_action.triggered.connect(self.actionClicked)
        self.menu_action2.triggered.connect(self.actionClicked)
        self.menu_action3.triggered.connect(self.actionClicked) 
        self.action4.triggered.connect(self.actionClicked)

        self.menu.addAction(self.menu_action)
        self.menu.addAction(self.menu_action2)                    
        self.menu.addAction(self.menu_action3) 
        self.menu.addAction(self.action4)        

        self.menu_bar.addMenu(self.menu)

    def actionClicked(self):
        action = self.sender()
        print(action.text())
        print(action.data())


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно ли изменить размер Option #1,2 и 3? в ширину и длину?

Comment: @imapw_ я добавил одну из возможностей, но это пусть будет последнее уточнение в данном вопросе.